# What are all the indeterminate forms and what are some well known examples of showing their indeterminacy?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, examples-counterexamples, indeterminate-forms

I'm assuming this is an exhaustive list of indeterminate forms:

$$\infty -\infty, \frac{0}{0}, \frac{\infty}{\infty}, 0 \cdot \infty, 1^\infty, \infty^0, 0^0$$

Are there canonical examples that show why these are considered indeterminate? I presume it means you can have two limits that evaluate to different real numbers and yet if you were to just blindly plug-and-chug directly you could end up with the same indeterminate form?

Comment: If one is shown to be indeterminate all the others fall as well since you can transform one to another with convenient operations. For example: $\infty - \infty = \ln(e^{\infty-\infty})=\ln(\frac{\infty}{\infty})$, $\frac{0}{0}=\frac{\frac{1}{0}}{\frac{1}{0}}=\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, $0\cdot\infty=\frac{\infty}{1/0}=\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, $1^{\infty}=e^{\infty\cdot\ln(1)}=e^{\infty\cdot 0}$, ...

Comment: For $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ use $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{an}{n}=a$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n}=\infty$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n^2}=0$, or even $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n(2+(-1)^n)}{n}$, which doesn't exist.